# C# Simulating mouseclicks in game doesn't work

Tags: c#, mouse, bots, simulate

Recently I tried to create a bot for an MMO-Game (called Florensia).
It should click on several positions in the game.
My problem is that it only sets the cursour to the position but the click doesn't work out. If I try it at my desktop or some other programs, it clicks correctly.
The game of course is in windowed mode and I already tried to set delays between the Mouseup and Mousedown.
Also to set the game to foreground window before the click didn't work.

Looking forward to any answers! :)

Comment: Please edit your question and add the code you are using, showing exactly where the problem is.

Comment: I used the code from the answer below now. (It still does not work).

Answer (score 0):

Try to use WinApi functions like in this example.

```
[DllImport("user32.dll")]
static extern IntPtr SendMessage(IntPtr hWnd, int msg, IntPtr wParam, IntPtr lParam);
[DllImport("user32.dll")]
static extern bool SetForegroundWindow(IntPtr hWnd);

static void Main(string[] args)
{
    const int WM_LBUTTONDOWN = 0x0201;
    const int WM_LBUTTONUP = 0x0202;
    const int MK_LBUTTON = 0x0001;

    uint x = 100;
    uint y = 100;

    IntPtr handle = new IntPtr(0x00090996); //Your window handle
    SetForegroundWindow(handle);
    Thread.Sleep(300);
    SendMessage(handle, WM_LBUTTONDOWN, new IntPtr(MK_LBUTTON), new IntPtr(y << 16 | x));
    Thread.Sleep(300);
    SendMessage(handle, WM_LBUTTONUP, new IntPtr(0), new IntPtr(y << 16 | x));
}
```

Comment: I just tried it out. It does again work in every window, I tested it but not in the game. Do you have any ideas or suggests on what the problem could be?

Comment: Try to call PostMessage instead of SendMessage. Maybe you use incorrect window handle and the area you want to click to is inside some child window? That's all I can suppose.

Comment: It didn't work with using PostMessage either but it can't be an incorrect window handle since the window is set to foreground whenever I use SetForegroundWindow(hWnd). Am I wrong?